# How to check Firebase data success write data in database (handle error)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

**How to check Firebase data success write data in database (handle error)?**

**because I want to set massage Toast if data write success show massage**

```
reg_money.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    FirebaseUser userfirebase = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Student/information");
                    String email = userfirebase.getEmail();
                    Uaser_register_money user = new Uaser_register_money(namesemster, email.substring(0,11), count2);

                    mDbRef.child("Student/information").setValue(user);





                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add Listeners

```
   mDbRef.child("Student/information").setValue(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            // Write was successful!
            // ...
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Write failed
            // ...
        }
    });
```